# Is there is a way for finding independent vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a subspace:

$$
W = \operatorname{Sp }\left\{
\begin{bmatrix}
2&1 \\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
0&3 \\
4&-5
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
-1&1 \\
2&-3
\end{bmatrix}
\right\}
$$

Is there an easy way to see that those matrices are linear dependent except for putting them as rows in a matrix and do REF?

Thanks.

Comment: You are right: row reduction to row-reduced echelon form is what we do.

Answer (score 1):

In this case it's easy because of the $0$ components in the first two matrices.

Obviously the second is independent of the first,

because any scalar multiple of the first will have a $0$ in the lower left.

If we have $a\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix}0&3\\4&-5\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-1&1\\2&-3\end{bmatrix}$,

then we must have $\begin{bmatrix}2a&a+3b\\4b&a-5b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-1&1\\2&-3\end{bmatrix},$

so obviously from the left components $2a=-1$ and $4b=2$; i.e., $a=-1/2$ and $b=1/2$,

and $a+3b=1$ and $a-5b=-3$, so these matrices are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply the third one by $2$ and add to the first one to get the second. Hence they are linearly dependent.

Comment: I intended to ask for a more general way for those questions. Is there is an easier way? you found a specific way for this matrix, so I conclude that the answer is - if you cant guess what is the linearity dependency, then no

Comment: If you are given just three matrices you can always find dependence this way. But if you have a large collection you cannot do this.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to do as you described and put them as rows of a matrix(Call it A).
Then, if you don't want to go through the row/column process, check $\det(A)$. if $\det(A)=0$ they are dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Any method essentially comes down to determining whether or not the equation $$a\begin{bmatrix}2&1 \\0&1\end{bmatrix} 
+ b\begin{bmatrix}0&3 \\4&-5\end{bmatrix}
+ c\begin{bmatrix}-1&1 \\2&-3\end{bmatrix}
= 0$$ has a nontrivial solution. This is basically a system of four linear equations in three unknowns, and you get the same system whether you expand the above equation directly or first flatten the matrices into vectors.

Now, as for the “best” method of determining whether or not this system admits a nontrivial solution, for artificially-constructed exercises like this one, it’s hard to go wrong with Gaussian elimination. However, as some of the other answers illustrate, it might be possible to eyeball a solution in specific cases. Taking advantage of zeros in the matrices/vectors is often fruitful and can save you some work. Even if you went so far as setting up the matrix to be reduced for this particular problem, you might be able to spot that the difference of two of the rows is a multiple of one of the others (again, try to take advantage of the zeros) and save yourself some work that way.